# Confirmation before running PHP script by default

Tags: php, command-line

Is it possible to configure the PHP CLI to confirm before executing a PHP script without putting confirmation logic on the file itself.

Ex:

> $ php filename.php
>
> Are you sure you want to run filename.php y/n

Comment: Maybe a `bash` script would do the work?

Comment: It's not. If it were, it would be extremely stupid. You can't modify an entire language and the whole binary just because you want a confirmation in CLI. To do that, you stick a one-liner that asks that question in your php script or create a shell script that does the whole php / question asking which lets you just do `./myscript.sh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a alias for this with a little bash script.

Add something like this to your .bashrc

```
confirm () {
    echo "Are you sure you want to run this php script [y/n] "
    read response
    if [[ $response =~ ^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])$ ]]; then
       echo "Confirmed"
    else
       exit 1;
    fi
}
```

And then add this to your .bashrc file

```
alias phpconfirm="confirm && php"
```

I strongly recommend using another name than php.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [readline](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readline.php) and the [php.ini auto_prepend_file directive](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) to handle the prompt.

While I don't think this is a good idea, I will give you a working answer since it is possible. If your php cli uses its own php.ini like some *nix distros do then this is easy. If not you will need to make sure your prompt script checks the current sapi and only executes when run from a [console with a tty](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-isatty.php)